# Backbone submit stucked

Tags: backbone.js

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <form action="/login" id="login_form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Login" id="login_form-login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="login_form-password">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is backbone code:

```
LoginForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#overlay"),
    events: {
        "submit #login_form" : "login",
    },
    login: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hello backbone");
    }
});

var login_view = new LoginForm();
```

Login function never called. I know that backbone is about models and templates, but is there any way to just bind event to existing html form?

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine. Please follow this fiddle to see it in action => https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/cxhy47hj/1/

Comment: Are you sure that `#overlay` exists when you call `$('#overlay')`? Maybe you should say `el: '#overlay'` instead. Or better, let the view create, own, and destroy its own `el` rather than trying to bind to an existing element.

Comment: While _mu is too short_ has probably given you what you need, you should include a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  I found the solution.

[*mu is too short*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572407/backbone-submit-stucked/40572509#comment68391966_40572407) was right - `#overlay` did not exist yet when the code was executed.

Here is the fix:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var login_view = new LoginForm();
    login_view.show();
});
```